# How to start tarantool console?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I've installed tarantool (tarantool_box) and tarantool-client. I can start tarantool

```
/usr/bin/tarantool_box --background
```

but when I try to connect to server

```
/usr/bin/tarantool
```

I see only admin console

```
localhost>
```

and can only use some commands and sql-like queries. I can not use any of commands from user guide, and almost all commands which start with `lua` fail:

```
lua console = require('console')
---
error: 'Lua error: [string "local console = require(''console'')"]:1: attempt to call global ''require'' (a nil value)'
...
```

Comment: You're using Tarantool 1.5, perhaps from your distro, it is too old. We're working on updating Tarantool in the distro, but this takes a lot of time with Debian release cycle. Try installing Tarantool from the official web site, and thinks will fall into their places.

Comment: @Kostja Please, point me to your official site, please. I used instruction from tarantool.org/download.html. Where can I find newest version? You mean build from tarantool.org/dist/master ?

Comment: No, you must have used some other instruction. tarantool.org/download.html doesn't provide a package which contains file /usr/bin/tarantool_box. This file is from Tarantool 1.5

Answer (score 1):

Solution, for clean Debian wheezy, found on tarantool github https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after update

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install libreadline-dev
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo git clone https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool
cd ./tarantool
sudo git submodule update --init --recursive
sudo cmake .
sudo make
```

after build

```
sudo ./tarantool/src/tarantool
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use this command for `docker` version of `tarantool/tarantool`:

```
tarantoolctl connect 3301
```

But you can also use `docker` directly

```
docker exec -it tarantool_1 console
```